# How can I enter manually IEEE 754 to a float?

Tags: c

I receive 3 arguments NaN, +infinity and -infinity and I want to generate manually NaN,+inf,-inf by changing the exponent and the mantissa of the IEEE 754 number.  How can I do it and save it after into a float array?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char*argv[]){

    int n=argc;
    float array[n];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){

       array[i]=argv[i];
       float number = argv[i];
       printf("the array[%f] is : %f",i,number);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why c# tag?....

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688630/how-is-infinity-represented-in-a-c-double

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remember that `argv[0]` is the name of the program. You should skip it in your loop.

Then for your problem, the values of the `argv` array are *strings*, that you need to convert to floating point values if that's what the supposed arguments are. For converting a string to a floating point value you can use [`strtof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof).