# Unusual conversion between float and long

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, bit-manipulation

I found a very complex function this is an implementation of *Fast inverse square root*. I honestly do not understand how this function works but the following conversion between a `long` and a `float` has caught my eye:

```
i  = *(long *) &y;
```

And I leave the full code

```
inline float Q_rsqrt(float number)
{
    long i;
    float x2, y;
    const float threehalfs = 1.5F;

    x2 = number * 0.5F;
    y  = number;
    i  = *(long *) &y;                      
    i  = 0x5f3759df - (i >> 1);            
    y  = * (float *) &i;
    y  = y * (threehalfs - (x2 * y * y));  

    return y;
}
```

Comment: @AShelly: Personally, I don't see this as a duplicate. This is a much, much narrower question.

Answer (score 7):

The cast simply reinterprets the bits of `y` as a `long` so that it can perform integer arithmetic on them.

See Wikipedia for an explanation of the algorithm: [Fast inverse square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root).

The code makes use of the knowledge that, on the target platform, `sizeof(long) == sizeof(float)`.

@R.. also helpfully adds the following in a comment:

> It's also invalid C -- it's an [aliasing violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). A correct version of this program needs use either `memcpy` or possibly (this is less clear that it's correct, but real compilers document support for it) [`union`-based type punning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442708/type-punning-and-unions-in-c). The version in OP's code will definitely be "miscompiled" (i.e. in a way different than the author's intent) by real compilers though.

This means that the code is not only architecture-specific, it is also compiler-specific.

Comment: It's also invalid C -- it's an aliasing violation. A correct version of this program needs use either `memcpy` or possibly (this is less clear that it's correct, but real compilers document support for it) `union`-based type punning. The version in OP's code will definitely be "miscompiled" (i.e. in a way different than the author's intent) by real compilers though.

Comment: @R.. - Thank you, I've added this to the answer (with attribution).

Comment: @NPE: where I can get more information about what you say

Comment: @CooperJames: Which part of it? ;-)

Comment: @CooperJames: I've added some links to the answer that might be helpful.

Comment: @NPE: more information on "cast simply reinterprets the bits"

Comment: @CooperJames: The same 32-bit pattern can be interpreted as an integer and as an IEEE float. The code takes the bits of the 32-bit float it is given, and looks at them as if they were the bits of a 32-bit integer. It then performs integer arithmetic on those bits to do its magic.

Comment: The only endianness assumption is that floating point and integer endianness match. This is, in practice, always true.

Comment: What's not true in practice is the assumption that `long` is 32-bit. `uint32_t` should be used instead.

Comment: @R.. The endianness matters in the magic constant, no?

Comment: @NPE: Nope. The constant is exactly the same for a little or big endian system as long as both integer and floating point types have matching endianness. It would only be wrong if they differed from each other.

Comment: @R.. Hm, I need to ponder this further. I'll delete that point from the answer until I've had a chance to think this through.